# rspec testing instance methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory

How can I test these instance methods with rspec and factory?

factories

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "example#{n}@gmail.com"
    password 'example0000'
    password_confirmation 'example0000'
    new_chat_notification { Faker::Number.between(0, 10) }
    new_other_notification { Faker::Number.between(0, 10) } 
  end

  factory :notification do
    notifiable_id { Faker::Number.between(1, 10) }
    notifiable_type { Faker::Lorem.word }
    action { Faker::Hipster.word }
    checked_at { Faker::Time.between(DateTime.now - 2, DateTime.now - 3)  }
    association :sender, factory: :user
    association :recipient, factory: :user
  end
end
```

user.rb

```
#check and decrease chat notification that happens between 2 given users (max 1)
def decreasing_chat_notification_number(user)
  notification = self.notifications.between_chat_recipient(user).unchecked.first
  self.checking_and_decreasing_notification(notification) if notification.present?
end

#check and decrease task notifications that happens between 2 given users
def decreasing_task_notification_number(user)
  self.notifications.task.between_other_recipient(user).unchecked.each do |notification|
    self.checking_and_decreasing_notification(notification)
  end
end
```

UPDATE

user.rb (here is the method that is called)

```
def checking_and_decreasing_notification(notification)
  notification.check_notification
  if notification.notifiable_type == "Message"
    decrease_new_chat_notifications
    decreased_chat_number_pusher
  else
    decrease_new_other_notifications
    decreased_other_number_pusher
  end
end
```

user_spec.rb

```
let(:sender) { create(:user) }
let(:user) { create(:user) }
let(:notification) { create(:notification, notifiable_type: "Message", recipient: user, sender: sender) }

it "decreasing_chat_notification_number" do
  allow(user).to receive(:checking_and_decreasing_notification).with(notification)
  user.decreasing_chat_notification_number(sender)
  expect(user).to receive(:checking_and_decreasing_notification).with(notification)
end
```

error message:

```
1) User instance methods decreasing_chat_notification_number
 Failure/Error: expect(user).to receive(:checking_and_decreasing_notification).with(notification)

   (#<User:0x007fefcfd6ce20>).checking_and_decreasing_notification(#<Notification id: 1, 
     recipient_id: 1, created_at: "2016-04-14 19:47:36", updated_at: "2016-04-14 19:47:36", 
     sender_id: 2, checked_at: "2016-04-12 02:32:50", notifiable_id: 4, notifiable_type: "Message", action: "tilde">)
   expected: 1 time with arguments: (#<Notification id: 1, 
     recipient_id: 1, created_at: "2016-04-14 19:47:36", updated_at: "2016-04-14 19:47:36", 
     sender_id: 2, checked_at: "2016-04-12 02:32:50", notifiable_id: 4, notifiable_type: "Message", action: "tilde">)
   received: 0 times
```

Comment: Call them and check that the appropriate changes were made? Not sure what aspect you need help with

Comment: My first time doing tests, so basically the whole approach for this kinda instance methods where you invoke new methods from the instance method. What data should I use? What should I check against ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(sidenote) You do not need `self` in your methods.

Take a look:

```
def decreasing_chat_notification_number(user)
  notification = notifications.between_chat_recipient(user).unchecked.first
  checking_and_decreasing_notification(notification) if notification.present?
end


describe '#decreasing_chat_notification_number' do
  let(:notification) { create(:notification) }
  let(:user)         { create(:user) }
  subject            { create(:user) }

  it 'your description' do
    expect(subject).to receive(:checking_and_decreasing_notification).with(notification)
    subject.decreasing_chat_notification_number(user)
  end
end
```

Comment: I know Andrey, just looks better this way :). Although you are right I should get used it.

Comment: Andrey, for some reason it's not working. Could you guess based on the updated question where it goes wrong?

Comment: @SzilardMagyar I showed you schematically how you'd expect the method call to result in calling another method. You have to set up the test users so that calling `decreasing_chat_notification_number` in fact resulted in `checking_and_decreasing_notification(notification)` to be called (meaning `notification.present?` should return `true`). How to do that only you know, because I do not know the login behind the `notifications.between_chat_recipient(user).unchecked.first` etc..

Comment: Thanks Andrey! I thought the error may happened cuz I missed something  not because of my data setup.

Comment: @SzilardMagyar no probs, hope you'll succeed in setting up the test data. You might also want to take a look at [rspec docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs)

Comment: Thanks for the source Andrey. The hardest part of testing for me by far is setting up the data for the tests. I've read a lot about it, still I'm totally confused.

Comment: @SzilardMagyar truly to say it was the hardest part for me as well at some point. The thing here is to set up right factories. Read (and try to implement) factories with `traits`, so that different "kinds" of the same resource are possible. Also to set up data in tests use `let` and `before do end` blocks, where you associate different resources if needed and stuff like that. It will come with time, word. ps [might be useful as well](https://github.com/reachlocal/rspec-style-guide)

Comment: Andrey found the problem. https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/expecting-messages. It's on your side, expect should be before calling the method. Could you pls update your answer for others who may see this answer. Thanks for the new resource too!

Comment: Meeeh, it's an evening typo, sorry, indeed it should have been before,  glad you've found the issue. Can I ask you to edit my answer since I'm from mobile phone and it won't be an easy task :D

Comment: Andrey one more question if you don't mind. I read both about `allow` and `expect` and as I saw people use only one at once. Why did you include both of them in here?

Comment: @SzilardMagyar here you basically do not want to have the `allow`. It is usually used to stub the method (and it's return value)